# Как проверить, сработала ли хоть одна проверка в цикле for?

Tags: python, for

Как проверить, сработала ли хоть одна проверка в цикле for

```
for x in range(len(word)):
    if letter == word[i]:
        cells[x] = letter
        pass
    i += 1
else: print('Такой буквы нет!')
```

Comment: `print(letter if letter in word else 'Такой буквы нет!')`

Comment: Размести print("Сработала"), после проверки, если делаешь в терминале. Или запусти в дебаггере.

Comment: Добавьте перед циклом флаг, типа `is_found = False`, в условии цикла поставьте флаг в `is_found = True`, а после цикла проверьте значение `is_found`, например: `if not is_found: print('Такой буквы нет!')`

Comment: На самом деле, не очень понятна конечная цель этого скрипта. Имеет ли он смысл (кроме чисто академического)? Если да, то опишите конечную задачу более подробно, возможно найдутся какие-то более элегантные решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать цикл `for`:

```
word = "Some word"
check_letter = "o"

for letter in word:
    if letter == check_letter:
        print(check_letter, "found!")
        break
else:
    print(check_letter, "not found!") # этот print 
    #вызовется только, если не вызвался break выше
```

Если `for` не обязателен - можно использовать вариант @Namerek:

```
print(letter if letter in word else 'Такой буквы нет!')
```

Или способ с `find()`:

```
print("found" if word.find(check_letter) != -1 else "not found")
```

(`find()` возвращает -1, если не найдено)

Comment: А мне кажется он ищет elelse какой-нибудь